# Block request that is possible ddos

Tags: centos, .htaccess, apache-2.4

How would i best block a request that takes on the following form in the acces

```
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:33:57 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:34:39 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:35:23 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:36:11 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:36:58 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:37:43 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:38:33 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:39:17 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:40:09 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:40:54 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
104.154.55.118 - - [19/Apr/2016:06:41:41 +0000] "GET /werken-bij/onze-opdrachtgevers/senior-big-data-architect-open-circle-solutions HTTP/1.1" 200 42072 "-" "curl/7.43.0"
```

There are 5000+ requests like this in the past 4 days. And it is straining the server. I am afraid that a simple IP block would be a easy workaround if someone would be intentionally doing this.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the above is the actual frequency those requests come, roughly once a minute, and that causes noticeable strain, you have different problems. :D [mod_ratelimit](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ratelimit.html) and/or https://www.modsecurity.org might help

Comment: I must admit that there are more problems with the server. and unfortunately this pushes the server into the strain limits.. As i am not that experienced in server management (i develop the PHP application) i start at what i seem to notice. And this was a noticeable request during the times that the server CPU spiked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To block 104.154.55.* addresses:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 104.154.55.0/24 -j DROP
```

To block 104.154.*.* addresses:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 104.154.0.0/16 -j DROP
```

To block 104.*.*.* addresses:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 104.0.0.0/8 -j DROP
```

Be careful when you block IP using this method. It may effect genuine traffic from reaching the host.

To block the current IP:

```
 iptables -A INPUT -s  -j DROP 104.154.55.118
```

This will block the current IP.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go by just the IP, you have several options.

- Rate limiting at the iptables OS level
- Rate limiting at the Webserver level (eg. Nginx does this nicely)
- Rate limiting / blocking with tools like Fail2Ban
- Blocking based on user agent; Here, clearly, it's curl and not a true browser. So even if IP changes, you could block, or slow down/rate limit based on this.

To go a little bit smarter than that, you can consider tools like Repsheet, which will help you classify traffic into trusted and less-trusted sources. Based on some matching rules, you could make this one less-trusted, and perform challenges like a reCaptcha, or give a response designed to alleviate the main server and hence real traffic, for example by serving this type of suspect visitor stale content from cache, or slow content from a secondary server.

But of course, consider the fact the IP may be from a trusted source like Google: http://www.ip2location.com/demo/104.154.55.118 Though the user agent doesn't hint at it being an official Google spider.

Comment: IP Trace was the first thing. But also take in mind that the ip owned by google can mean it is just a bot running in the google app cloud of someone who rents a server there